# PFQuery returns just 100 objects (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I created a PFQuery to fetch all the objects in class "Albums" (512 objects).

When I'm creating a PFQuery and calling `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method on it, it returns just 100 objects instead of 512, although I added the line

```
query.limit=1000;
```

My code:

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Albums"];
query.limit=1000;

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    NSLog(@"%lu",objects.count); //print - 100
    self.albums=objects;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.supermarkets.count); //print - 100
}];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PFQuery Only Returning 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771677/pfquery-only-returning-100)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery
..

```
NSMutableArray *allObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger limit = 0;
__block NSUInteger skip = 0;
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
[query setLimit: limit];
[query setSkip: skip];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded. Add the returned objects to allObjects
    [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
    if (objects.count == limit) {
      // There might be more objects in the table. Update the skip value and execute the query again.
      skip += limit;
      [query setSkip: skip]; //from here you run the query again with new offset  

    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```